# How to file 8843 form not filed before

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident

I was wondering how an F2 visa with no income who has not filed the 8843 in the last 3 years can file this. I have not been able to find the correct procedure to file these forms. I am trying to file for 2017, 2018, 2019.

If anyone has any information please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you were not required to file a federal income tax return for those years (e.g. your income was below the threshold for needing to file), you can just send in the Form 8843 (using the correct version of the form from each applicable year) by itself.

From the Form 8843 instructions (on page 3 of the [Form 8843 PDF](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8843.pdf)), section "When and Where To File":

> If you don’t have to file a 2019 tax return, mail Form 8843 to the
>   Department of the Treasury, Internal Revenue Service Center, Austin,
>   TX 73301-0215 by the due date (including extensions) for filing Form
>   1040-NR or Form 1040-NR-EZ.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question. Do you know if the old 8843 forms should be mailed together with the 2019 or should all forms be mailed separately.

Comment: @Heisenberg: I don't know

Comment: I'd mail them together but with a cover letter explaining what I was doing. But spending a few more cents on additional envelopes and stamps certainly shouldn't _hurt_ anything, especially if (again) you include a cover letter on each saying the others are on their way.